# Google Cloud Vision API: Detect Logos TypeError

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to implement the [detect_logos](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-logos) functionality on my local machine in Python 2.7.

I have a function that was originally Google's label.py file that is given in [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/api/label).

I eventually edited the main function and it calls detect_logos() after spitting out some labels. I am now running into the following error in the **detect_logos(path)** function at line "**logos = image.detect_logos()**".

**TypeError: construct_settings() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metrics_headers'**

This error apparently stems from the immage_annotator_client.py file within the vision api. I must be missing something.

```
def detectLabelsLogos(photo_file):

    #configurable options: FREE TO CHANGE
    resizedFileName = 'clone.jpeg'  #name of resized files (are deleted at the end)
    labelCount = 5                  #max number of labels 

    #nonconfigurable options: DO NOT TOUCH
    resized = False
    filename = photo_file
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('vision', 'v1')

    #initial size check
    imgSizeInBytes = os.stat(photo_file).st_size

    if imgSizeInBytes >= MAX_IMAGE_SIZE_IN_BYTES:
        print "\n[Image too large...resizing...]"
        resized = True
        filename = resizedFileName

        with Image.open(photo_file) as image:
            newimg = resizeimage.resize_thumbnail(image, [1600, 800])
            newimg.save(filename, image.format)
            newimg.close()

    imgSizeInBytes = os.stat(filename).st_size

    #ensure file is not empty
    if imgSizeInBytes > 0:
        # [START construct_request]
        with open(filename, 'rb') as image:
            image_content = base64.b64encode(image.read())
            service_request = service.images().annotate(body={
                'requests': [{
                    'image': {
                        'content': image_content.decode('UTF-8')
                    },
                    'features': [{
                        'type': 'LABEL_DETECTION',
                        'maxResults': labelCount
                    }]
                }]
            })
        # [END construct_request]

            # [START parse_response]
            response = service_request.execute()

            detect_logos(filename);

            for i in range(0, labelCount):
                if i >= len(response['responses'][0]['labelAnnotations']):
                    print "\n[Exhausted Responses]"
                    break
                label = response['responses'][0]['labelAnnotations'][i]['description']
                print('\nFound label: %s' % (label))
            # [END parse_response]

            image.close()

        #delete resized file
        if resized:
            os.remove(filename)   
else:
    print "[Invalid File Input: Empty File]"

print "\n"

def detect_logos(path):
    """Detects logos in the file."""

    vision_client = vision.Client()
    print vision_client

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision_client.image(content=content)

    logos = image.detect_logos()
    print('\nLogos:')

    for logo in logos:
        print(logo.description)
```

I have also been doing "set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/blah/blah/serviceaccountkey.json"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the `google.cloud` client library for the Vision API instead.

Check out [the label detection demo](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/vision-usage.html#label-detection) which does what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
>>> from google.cloud import vision
>>> client = vision.Client()
>>> image = client.image(source_uri='gs://my-storage-bucket/image.jpg')
>>> labels = image.detect_labels(limit=3)
>>> labels[0].description
'automobile'
>>> labels[0].score
0.9863683
```

PS: Don't forget [the authentication step](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/vision-usage.html#authentication-and-configuration)! You need to use a service account with Cloud Vision (the old `gcloud auth login` won't work).